# matplotlib showing empty plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Python 2.7 and matplotlib to create a simple plot window on Ubuntu 12.10.

When `plt.plot()` is called, an empty windows comes up, but closes instantaneously, without displaying any figure inside it, only a grey background. However, if I try with `plt.savefig('name')` the correct figure is saved.

Also, I guess it is important to mention that I do have `plt.show()` at the end. A plot window does appear, it's just blank.

Some code:

```
def plot(self):
        # Plotting the track
        coordinates = np.genfromtxt(self.data, delimiter=self.coord_delimiter)

        plt.plot(coordinates[:, 0:1], coordinates[:, 1:2], linestyle='-', color=self.track_color, linewidth='2')

        plt.savefig('m1') # This works
        plt.show()
```

What could cause the plot window to be blank, but the saved image to be correct?

Comment: do you have plt.show() at the end?

Comment: @NKN: yes, I do. My mistake for not mentioning it in the post. I do have plt.show(). This is why a window does come up, the problem is that it is blank.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: @NKN: just edited my original post. Just not sure about how useful it's going to be.

Comment: are you plotting multi-graphs on the same figure? (because the color here is a variable). if this is the problem you need to use hold and make it true and false properly. I think python is waiting for the next data to plot!!

Comment: I would change this line : plt.plot(coordinates[:, 0:1], coordinates[:, 1:2], linestyle='-', color=self.track_color, linewidth='2') to something very simple to see where the problem begins : plt.plot(coordinates[:, 0], coordinates[:, 1])

Comment: May need some of your data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Are you running this as as script, or interactively?

Answer (score -3):

It's been a while now, but if I remember correctly, I think I used:

```
plt.block(True);
```

in order to get it fixed.

Comment: That gives me: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'block'` for matplotlib 1.4.2.

Comment: Depends what you `plt` variable points to. For me, I believe that was pyplot: `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`